# What's the gardening term for the dish you put under under a planters holes?

Tags: houseplants, tools

What's the technical name for the dish you place under a planters holes that catches water from it? Googling 'dishes' when I look for a gardening water catching dish returns kitchen dishes, when I am looking instead for the gardening ones. I realize I might use some kitchen dishes for this purpose, but I imagine that gardeners have a specific term for this item.

Answer (score 3):

I've always heard and used "saucer", which probably came from the practice of using actual old glass/china saucers under plants. Gardeners tend to be a thrifty lot and have been following the "reuse/recycle" ethos for decades, if not forever. Personally, I've used old saucers, pie tins, layer cake pans, square cake pans, and many other castaways as plant saucers. I have only once purchased a saucer, and that's because it came with the pot.

BTW, in the US the major online retailers agree with this term and typically have these receptacles listed as "plant saucers".

Comment: UK retailers also call them "plant saucers".

Answer (score 2):

Try googling 'plant pot drip trays' as well, you're more likely to be shown a range of trays suitable for plants rather than china in the kitchen... If you want a decorative outer pot to stand a plant pot in, that's usually called a cache pot. Most of these don't have drainage holes, though some may have a hole with a matching saucer or tray beneath.